# Harden against privilege escalation in Microservices

Tags: encryption, session-management, privilege-escalation

Please consider the following scenario.

- The system has a set of business owners (i.e. users of the system)
- Each business owner is mapped to a set of customers
- The business owners login to the system in order to manage their customers.

The business owners will select a single customer first, and from there onward his *session is bound that selected customer*.

I have a set of microservices, each requires a `Customer-ID` for processing. i.e.

- Microservice A exposes `GET /resource-a/{customer-id}`
- Microservice B exposes `POST /resource-b/{customer-id}`
- etc.

The `Customer-Id` is considered to be a sensitive information - so that it is in encrypted form.

However it's still vulnerable to **privilege-escalation**. i.e. one business owner may mistakenly share the encrypted customer-id through bookmarks etc. so that a business owner may access details of customers who aren't mapped to him. (not exactly privilege-escalation?)

- I want to avoid server-side authorization of customer-id against business owner because it is known to be a slow operation and and 90% of the APIs will have to repeat this authorization process
- All the microservices are stateless, so that it's not possible to encrypt the `Customer-Id` with the session-id as the key (since no stateful microservices/ session)
- Also I don't think it's a good idea to do this authorization at the gateway since it's not intended to perform such business logic.

How can I prevent privilege escalation in this situation?

Comment: `I want to avoid server-side ... because slow` Well, but if it's necessary then it's necessary.  Try to optimize your DB etc., but please don't choose fast execution over security.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you don't want to do this on server-side, I see only two other possibilities:

- Go with `security through obscurity`, and never expose the `Customer-Id` on user facing (any action that make it show up in address bar, UI, browser history etc.). This won't patch your problem and will not protect you against a dedicated attacker. Though it might work at certain degree.
- Use Stateless Self-Contained Tokens (eg. JWT) for generating the user session. And store all the `customer-id's` that are bound to that user on the token itself. Then, when you verify the session token server-side, you will also get authorization at same time. This would not cost in performance at all. Though, it might work as a solution only as far as you wont have a lot a `customer-ids` bound to a user (obviously you don't want the whole DB in the token).